# Find $p\in\mathbb{P}$ such that $p_{n,\lambda}=p+\lambda\cdot10630620+\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n2^r\in\mathbb{P}$ for $n=1,2,...,9$ and $\lambda=0,1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers.

What is the smallest value of $p\in\mathbb{P}$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. For $n=1,2,3,...,9$, $$p_{n,0}=p+\sum_{r=1}^n2^r\in\mathbb{P}$$
2. For $n=1,2,3,...,9,$ $$p_{n,1}=p+10630620+\sum_{r=1}^n2^r\in\mathbb{P}$$

To reiterate the title:

> Find  the smallest value of $p\in\mathbb{P}$ such that
>   $p_{n,\lambda}=p+\lambda\cdot10630620+\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n2^r\in\mathbb{P}$
>   for $n=1,2,...,9$ and $\lambda=0,1$.

This is a "puzzle" of my own making. I have the solution, but I'm curious to see other methods, especially ones that do not require brute force. Good luck!

---

Kudos to dan_fulea for solving this!

```
2397347207, 2397347209, 2397347213, 2397347221, 2397347237, 2397347269, 2397347333, 2397347461, 2397347717, 2397348229
2407977827, 2407977829, 2407977833, 2407977841, 2407977857, 2407977889, 2407977953, 2407978081, 2407978337, 2407978849
```

Comment: Already the first conidtion has no solution up to $10^9$, so any solution would have to be $\gg$ all summands used in the problem statement. Under these circumstances, I find it a bit unplausible that a solution (if found) can be shown to be unique.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I rephrased it to "find the smallest $p$", just in case there are multiple primes which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: The prime in question is greater than $10^9$

Comment: Where does $10630620$ come from?

Comment: @ConnorHarris  Funny enough, once you find the smallest prime satisfying the first condition, the second condition is easy to verify. $2397347207$ is the smallest prime such that $2397347207+\sum_{r=1}^n 2^r \in \mathbb{P}$ for $n=1,2,...,9$ it also happens that $2397347207+10630620+\sum_{r=1}^n 2^r \in \mathbb{P}$ for $n=1,2,...,9$.  $10630620$ is an interesting number, so I decided to include it in the puzzle, even though it didn't really add to the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a third search...

```
sage: var('k');
sage: S = [ sum(2^k, k, 1, n) for n in [1..9] ]
sage: SJ = cartesian_product( [S, [0,1]] )
sage: for p in primes(10^9, 10^10):
....:     still_ok = True
....:     for s, j in SJ:
....:         q = p + s + j*10630620
....:         if not q.is_prime():
....:             still_ok = False
....:             break
....:     if still_ok:
....:         print p
....:         break
....:     
2397347207
```

Comment: Outstanding. I'm just curious: how long did it take for your program to finish running?

Comment: It was started immediately after the comment of Hagen von Eitzen in a new session, while the search first search up to $10^8$ was finished, and the second search up to $10^9$ was still running. At some point i was letting the computer work, came back, saw no solution in the second search, and the above solution in the final search was immediately copy+pasted. I would say half an hour on an old laptop. Thanks for posting the puzzle!

Comment: Wow, I'm baffled. It took my computer half a day. I think my program is just very clunky and slow. Kudos for solving!